# Can ExtendScript replace a FootageItem with an Illustrator file and specify a certain layer?

Tags: extendscript, after-effects

In AfterEffects, I can right click on a file in the Project panel, then select "Replace Footage".  After choosing an Illustrator file, the window below appears, which allows me to select a particular layer from that Illustrator file.

[image]

**Is it possible to replace a FootageItem using ExtendScript and specify a certain layer of an Illustrator file?**

Basics on the documentation, I've only found the FootageItem.replace( ) method.  However, when I use this method, I'm unable to specify a layer of the Illustrator file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the scripting guide:

> app.project.item(index).layer(index).replaceSource (newSource, fixExpressions)
>
> Description:
> Replaces the source for this layer.
>
> Parameters:
>
> newSource
> The new source AVItem object.
>
> fixExpressions
> True to adjust expressions for the new source, false otherwise. Note that this feature can be resource-intensive; if replacing a large amount of footage, do this only at the end of the operation. See also "Project autoFixExpressions() method" on page 115.
>
> Returns: Nothing.

So I guess you should do two steps.

1. Import your .ai file via `new ImportOptions(file);`
2. replace the source of your AVLayer

Comment: Thanks @fabiantheblind .  I really appreciate the answer.